# How to keep a reference to a RequireJS module?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to figure out how RequireJS works, but the RequireJS website is very unclear on explaining the basics, especially concerning how to use the 'require' and 'define' methods.

I have the following example running:

```
//module1.js
define([], function () {
    var returnedModule = function () {
        var _name = 'whoa I am a module';
        this.getName = function () {
            return _name;
        }
    };
    return returnedModule;
});

//main.js
require(['module1'], function(temp_reference){
    var m = new temp_reference();
    console.log("created module: " + m.getName());
});

// ... some other code ...

// now, if I need the module1.js again, do I need to require it again??
```

My question: do I need to "require" this module1.js file every time I want to do something with it? (in this case creating a new m() object from the temporary reference).

Can't I keep the result of the require call somewhere instead of only having it available inside the callback?

EDIT

I thought I could solve the issue by keeping a reference this way:

```
// keep the required module available
var myModule = require("module1");
```

But this generates an error: *module1 is not yet loaded.*

Comment: Yes - that's the whole point of modularity. If you need your module somewhere else (in another module than `main`) again, you'll have to declare it as a dependency there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Require JS is an AMD - Async module definition meaning the modules are loaded into the document when you require it. It kinda provides a functional scope/modular approach to your JavaScript code, say like **import** keyword in Java or **Using** key word in C#.

**Now answer to your question :** Yes you need to reference the defined module in your require module to get its reference as a functional parameter.

For example consider the below code

http://jsfiddle.net/NssGv/52/

```
define('a', {
   add: function(x, y){
     return console.log(x + y);
   }
 });

// Use the module (import)
require(['a'], function(a){
    a.add(1, 2);
});

require(['a'], function(a){
    a.add(4, 6);
});
```

In this code context , **a** - is module definition that is imported by the other modules to access **add()** method of the defined module.

Require JS constructs a module tree and saves all the defined module in this tree with the name of the module. In tis example its - **a** (this is called named module)

This tree can be accessed as below through dev console

```
window.requirejs.s.contexts._.defined.a
```

**And my output would like this:**

[image]

When ever your load an external modular file Require JS creates a `<script>` tag and appends it into the document `<head>`

**Consider your example:**

Working plunker link : http://plnkr.co/edit/eNQkcfwftkYSY00wMPeI?p=preview

When the below entry point codes are executed

HTML:

```
<script src="xdomain/require.js" data-main="script"></script>
```

JS:

```
require(['module1'], function(temp_reference){
    var m = new temp_reference();
    console.log("created module: " + m.getName());
});
```

Require JS attaches 2 files namely **script.js** *(referenced in script tag in HTML head as main script file)* and second is **module1.js** *(referenced in script.js)*

[image]

After attaching this file to the head asynchronously the code in the modules is executed and the resultant of the module will be pushed to the requirejs module tree as mentioned earlier.

Later these modules are injected into the reference modules based on your dependencies definition you pass as array to the require function.

> require([{{YOUR_DEPENDENCIES}}], function({{INJECTED_REFERENCES}}){
>   --Your code--});

---

**This is what you are trying to achieve(Not suggested)**

http://plnkr.co/edit/5SYoNf8xNL1DcMfjuy0Y?p=preview

```
var myModule; //Global variable
require(['require', 'module1'], function(require){
    myModule = require("module1");
    var m = new myModule();
    console.log("created module: " + m.getName());
});
```

**You can also try this Hacky!**

http://plnkr.co/edit/Rr34HlhOiyja6XnwH8fw?p=preview

```
var myModule; //Global variable
require(['module1'], function(){
    myModule = window.requirejs.s.contexts._.defined.module1;
    var m = new myModule();
    console.log("created module: " + m.getName());
});
```

---

### Finally

Require JS is giving the javascript modularity approach and on demand loading of scripts rather than preloaded in the memory. This saves some memory and also contribute to the speed of your web app. Your code becomes structured automatically and will be easy to maintain.